# Syntax error in SQL FROM clause

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, ado

I think my syntax is correct. Whats wrong with my syntax? I need to use it as search item.

But still it shows the error

> Syntax error in FROM clause

```pascal
procedure TForm9.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ADOQuery1.Close;

ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('SELECT DAT20303.NUM,DAT20303.NAMA,DAT20303.MATRIC_ID,DAT20303.SUBJEK,DAT20303.M1,DAT20303.M2,DAT20303.M3,DAT20303.M4,DAT20303.M5,DAT20303.M6,DAT20303.M7, STUDENT.SEKSYEN,STUDENT.MATRIC_ID');
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('FROM STUDENT');
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('JOIN DAT20303');
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('ON DAT20303.MATRIC_ID = STUDENT.MATRIC_ID');
 ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('WHERE SEKSYEN = ' + ComboBox2.Text);



ADOQuery1.Open; {open query + display data}
end;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: and also missing a space **before** the `FROM` after the last column in the list of `SELECT` columns ....

Comment: `ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('WHERE SEKSYEN = ''' + ComboBox2.Text + '''');` but best to use parameters as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Beware of SQL injection

Comment: thankyou @marc_s . im sorry for not noticing that space. -___- okay parameter . im new to delphi. still trying to learn. thanks guys! big thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Do you in fact have a `STUDENT` table? You refer to both `STUDENT` and `LSTUDENT` in your `SELECT`, but only use `STUDENT` in the `FROM` clause. Which one is it?

Also, at a minimum, you need to quote the content of your `WHERE` condition.

```pascal
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('WHERE SEKSYEN = ' + QuotedStr(ComboBox2.Text));
```

**Much better** though would be to *stop concatenating SQL in your code*, and use parameterized queries instead. It's not only much safer against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but it allows the database engine to compile and cache the query content, making it execute much more quickly if you're using the same statement more than one time with different parameter values.

```pascal
procedure TForm9.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.Close;

  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT DAT20303.NUM, DAT20303.NAMA, DAT20303.MATRIC_ID,');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('DAT20303.SUBJEK, DAT20303.M1, DAT20303.M2, DAT20303.M3,');   
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('DAT20303.M4, DAT20303.M5, DAT20303.M6,');    
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('DAT20303.M7, STUDENT.SEKSYEN, LSTUDENT.MATRIC_ID');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('FROM STUDENT');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('JOIN DAT20303');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('ON DAT20303.MATRIC_ID = STUDENT.MATRIC_ID');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add ('WHERE SEKSYEN = :SekSyen');
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('SekSyen').AsString := ComboBox1.Text;
  ADOQuery1.Open; {open query + display data}
end;
```

And *please* don't be afraid to use whitespace (spaces and line breaks) to make your SQL more readable! I've cleaned it up somewhat in my answer to do so. When it's easier to read, it's easier to understand (and maintain later).

Comment: thank you! this is new. i always thought that i can only use the sql command line by line.  thank you very much. im bad in english -__-

Comment: @Adam: You *do* have to use all of the SQL. My first code snippet only corrects the one line having the error - you'll still need to use all of the SQL above it.

Comment: do check my other question. the last one. :) [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640490/adoquery1-parameter-card-not-found[link]

Answer (score 4):

You must not use only `JOIN` within your query.

This

```sql
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT
  JOIN DAT20303 ON DAT20303.MATRIC_ID = STUDENT.MATRIC_ID
```

leads to

> Syntax error in FROM clause

but this will do fine

```sql
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT
  LEFT JOIN DAT20303 ON DAT20303.MATRIC_ID = STUDENT.MATRIC_ID
```

or this one

```sql
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT
  INNER JOIN DAT20303 ON DAT20303.MATRIC_ID = STUDENT.MATRIC_ID
```

Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998423/full-join-on-ms-access) here on SO