# ADOQuery1 parameter 'card' not found

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado

i've  used the parameter method but now i have a problem. i want to insert all my data inside the table. i need to insert 2 table at once. so heres my full coding. need help. why it says like that?

```
ADOQuery1.Close();
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO STUDENT (CARD_ID,NAMA,MATRIC_ID,SUBJEK,KURSUS,FAKULTI,Seksyen,TAHUN) VALUES ');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('(card,nama,matric,subjek,kursus,fakulti,seksyen,tahun)');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO subjek2 (CARD_ID, MATRIC_ID,NAMA,SUBJEK) VALUES');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('(card,matric,nama,subjek)');

ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('card').Value:= card1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('nama').Value:= Edit1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('matric').Value:= Edit2.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('kursus').Value:= Edit3.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('fakulti').Value:= Edit4.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('seksyen').Value:= ComboBox1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('tahun').Value:= Edit5.Text;

ADOQuery1.Open();
```

Comment: This code is from your previous question and we know that this code is **not working**. Why do you post wrong code? Where is the code related to insert?

Comment: @SirRufo : sorry for the wrong paste. could you check it ? i've change to the right ones. thankyou and sorry.

Comment: You've changed the entire code after I posted my answer, which invalidates my answer. It's a little difficult to hit a constantly moving target. Please **don't do that** - it's unfair to people who answer your question only to have the entire question change, because it makes their answers totally wrong (and sometimes makes them look pretty foolish) and can cost them reputation. Once you've received an answer, **don't change the entire question**.

Comment: @KenWhite im sorry about it. im still new in stackoverflow. so after this i should posted a new question?  but this is last. i will not edit it again. i've tried playing around with the params. but when i delete the param 'card', its the next param not found. same if i repeat by deleting the second param. later the third param pops out said 'not found'

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to match your **new code**. Please don't change it entirely again. Thanks. (You should also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).)

Comment: advice taken. but still the problem is not solved yet. same error

Comment: I've addressed the "same error" in the comments you made to my answer. If you want us to help you, you need to **actually read the answers you're given**. Here's some more advice: If you're struggling that badly to do it all in one query with multiple statements, *separate it out into two queries*.  until you can get them each working, and *then* work on combining them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues in your code.

### SQL-Statement

If you want to execute more than one statement, then you have to use the statement delimiter (most times `;`). You missed that in your statements.

```sql
INSERT INTO STUDENT (CARD_ID,NAMA,MATRIC_ID,SUBJEK,KURSUS,FAKULTI,Seksyen,TAHUN) VALUES
(card,nama,matric,subjek,kursus,fakulti,seksyen,tahun); -- missed ;
INSERT INTO subjek2 (CARD_ID, MATRIC_ID,NAMA,SUBJEK) VALUES
(card,matric,nama,subjek); -- optional on last statement
```

### Parameters

Parameters in SQL-Statements must start with `:` otherwise they were treated as normal fields

```sql
INSERT INTO STUDENT (CARD_ID,NAMA,MATRIC_ID,SUBJEK,KURSUS,FAKULTI,Seksyen,TAHUN) VALUES
(:card,:nama,:matric,:subjek,:kursus,:fakulti,:seksyen,:tahun);
INSERT INTO subjek2 (CARD_ID, MATRIC_ID,NAMA,SUBJEK) VALUES
(:card,:matric,:nama,:subjek);
```

BTW: You did not provide any data to the parameter `subjek` in your code.

### Executing Statement

Some statements return a cursor to data (`SELECT`) others do not (`INSERT`,`DELETE`,...).

If you are executing a statement, that did not return a cursor then you must not use [`Open`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Open). Instead you have to [`ExecSQL`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery.ExecSQL).

### Mutiple Statements / Access / `TADOQuery`

You simply can not execute multiple statements using `TADOQuery` and Access. You have to execute the statements separately.

If you want to achieve, that all data is written or if any error occurs no data is written, then you have to start a **transaction** before the statements and you can **commit** or **rollback**.

---

Following all the advices you come to the following code (without transaction)

```
ADOQuery1.Close();
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO STUDENT (CARD_ID,NAMA,MATRIC_ID,SUBJEK,KURSUS,FAKULTI,Seksyen,TAHUN) VALUES ');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('(:card,:nama,:matric,:subjek,:kursus,:fakulti,:seksyen,:tahun)');

ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('card').Value:= card1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('nama').Value:= Edit1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('matric').Value:= Edit2.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('subjek').Value:= '????'; // I don't know what
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('kursus').Value:= Edit3.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('fakulti').Value:= Edit4.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('seksyen').Value:= ComboBox1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('tahun').Value:= Edit5.Text;

ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO subjek2 (CARD_ID, MATRIC_ID,NAMA,SUBJEK) VALUES');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('(:card,:matric,:nama,:subjek)');
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('card').Value:= card1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('nama').Value:= Edit1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('matric').Value:= Edit2.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('subjek').Value:= '????'; // I don't know what

ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Answer (score 4):

You've not provided the parameters correctly (as I showed you in my previous answer). Note the colon (`:`) before the name of each parameter:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('(:card, :matric, :nama, :subjek)');
```

Also note (from that same previous answer) that you do **not** use the colon when assigning values to the paramters:

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('card').Value := card1.Text;
```

And, once again, *use white space in your SQL*!! You save one keystroke by not putting spaces in between the comma-separated things, and make it *much* more difficult to read and maintain later without them. It's much easier to read `(:card, :matric, :nama, :subjek)` than it is to read `(:card,:matric,:nama,:subjek)`. Start learning to do things properly now and save yourself (and others) headaches later.

Comment: There is one issue left. There are two parameters named `card` and `ParamByName('card')` will only return the first one (same to `matric,nama,subjek`). Parameters should have unique names or must be addressed by index. But maybe that will be the answer to the next question ;)

Comment: Then name them differently, and set them from the same variable. `Parameters.ParamByName('cardA').Value := card1.Text; Parameters.ParamByName('cardB').Value := card1.Text;`. Some database drivers (like Access, apparently) won't repeat the parameter assignment, and some will. That's yet *a different question* than the one asked here.