# Combining two tables in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel VBA I would like to be able to combine two tables in excel with a common key. I have suggested ADODB as a method,but am open to any other more efficient/elegant methods. Please see below for a minimal example:

I have the below to start with...

Sheet1

```
    A     B       C
 1 type year1   year2
 2 aaa  100     110
 3 bbb  220     240
 4 ccc  304     200
 5 ddd  20      30
 6 eee  440     20
```

Sheet2

```
    A     B       C
 1 type year1   year2
 2 bbb  10      76
 3 ccc  44      39
 4 ddd  50      29
 5 eee  22      23
 6 fff  45      55
```

And would like to combine it so that I have the following as a result:

Sheet3

```
    A     B       C       D       E
 1 type year1   year2   year1   year2
 2 aaa  100      110      0       0
 3 bbb  220      240      10      76
 4 ccc  304      200      44      39
 5 ddd  20       30       50      29
 6 eee  440      20       22      23
 7 fff  0        0        45      55
```

Have done a bit of googling and SQL type outer joins seems close but not sure how to implement it.

Below is the code used to try and implement it so far...

```
Option Explicit



Sub JoinTables()

 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection


 With cn
     .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
     .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
         "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
     .Open
 End With

 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

 rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] OUTER JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet1$].[type] = " & _
     "[Sheet2$].[type]", cn

 With Worksheets("Sheet3")
     .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
 End With

 rs.Close
 cn.Close

 End Sub
```

Comment: Code tried now added...

Comment: beautiful! now that's a better question.

Comment: tell you what - *`full outer join`* is not supported by ADODB in VBA I think so why don't you have a look in [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998423/full-join-on-ms-access) and maybe you can come up with a solution yourself?

Comment: Also [alternatives](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/19/Full-Outer-Joins.aspx)

Comment: @h.l.m http://superuser.com/questions/537339/how-do-i-merge-two-tables-in-excel-that-have-identical-columns might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether or not you have duplicate values on either sheet, I could think of a few ideas, not using SQL though.

- Get LastRow of SourceSheet1 & SourceSheet2 - Set them as variables lastRow1 & lastRow2
- Create a row ticker for each sheet.  s1Row, s2Row, tRow
- set tRow = 2 For the TargetSheet's first line
- Use For loop to cycle through each row of SourceSheet1.  Using something like this
- When the first part of code is done looping, you will be finished adding every item from SourceSheet1 onto the TargetSheet.  Then you will have to check the values from SourceSheet2 to see if any were unique to that list.
- When that is done, you should have only added the ones that were missing from your initial search.  Then the targetSheet will be in the order of SourceSheet1 All Items, then the extra items from SourceSheet2

SET VARIABLES

```
Private Sub JoinLists()

Dim rng As Range
Dim typeName As String
Dim matchCount As Integer
Dim s1Row As Integer
Dim s2Row As Integer
Dim tRow As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim lastRow1 As Integer
Dim lastRow2 As Integer
Dim SourceSheet1 As String
Dim SourceSheet2 As String
Dim TargetSheet As String

SourceSheet1 = "Source1"
SourceSheet2 = "Source2"
TargetSheet = "Target"

tRow = 2

lastRow1 = Sheets(SourceSheet1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row
lastRow2 = Sheets(SourceSheet2).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row
```

PHASE ONE: Copying every entry from Sheet1 to Target, while grabbing matches from Sheet2

```
Set rng = Sheets(SourceSheet2).Range("A2:A" & lastRow2)

For s1Row = 2 To lastRow1
    typeName = Sheets(SourceSheet1).Cells(s1Row, 1)
    matchCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, typeName)

    'Set the Row up on the TargetSheet. No matter if it's a match.
    Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 1) = typeName
    Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 2) = Sheets(SourceSheet1).Cells(s1Row, 2)
    Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 3) = Sheets(SourceSheet1).Cells(s1Row, 3)

    'Check to see if there are any matches on SourceSheet2

    If matchCount = 0 Then
    'There are NO matches.  Add Zeros to the extra columns
        Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 4) = 0
        Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 5) = 0
    Else
       'Get first matching occurance on the SourceSheet2
        m = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(typeName, rng, 0)
        'Get Absolute Row number of that match
        s2Row = m + 1    ' This takes into account the Header Row, as index 1 is Row 2 of the search Range
        'Set the extra columns on TargetSheet to the Matches on SourceSheet2
        Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 4) = Sheets(SourceSheet1).Cells(s2Row, 2)
        Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 5) = Sheets(SourceSheet1).Cells(s2Row, 3)
    End If

    tRow = tRow + 1
Next s1Row
```

PHASE TWO: Checking SourceSheet2 for Entries NOT on Sheet1

```
Set rng = Sheets(SourceSheet1).Range("A2:A" & lastRow1)

For s2Row = 2 To lastRow2
    typeName = Sheets(SourceSheet2).Cells(s2Row, 1)
    matchCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, typeName)

    If matchCount = 0 Then
    'There are NO matches.  Add to Target Sheet
        Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 1) = typeName
        Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 2) = 0
        Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 3) = 0
        Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 4) = Sheets(SourceSheet2).Cells(s2Row, 2)
        Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(tRow, 5) = Sheets(SourceSheet2).Cells(s2Row, 3)
        tRow = tRow + 1
    'Not doing anything for the matches, because they were already added.
    End If
Next s2Row
End Sub
```

[image: Finished Tested Code Results]

EDIT: typo correction

Comment: Great, elaborate answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Do you happen to know if there's a VBA library that abstracts this complexity to the SQL-like level? Maybe some adoption of SQLite? I'm not even sure if VBA supports third party libraries inclusion. Maybe just open source VBA utility functions then that abstract this.