# Merge Two Excel Tables Using VBA and Condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with two large datasets (900K lines each; 8 columns). Power Query isn't handling the merge (system limitation) so I was thinking about incorporating VBA to merge and filter a large portion of data so it's manageable.

Can you please assist?

Criteria:

- *Column P in both* - will be used to merge (common between both sets)
- If *Column E = C*, true then remove  all TRUES from both sets
- If ABS(C2-D2 X E2)<0.03, true then remove all TRUES from both sets

Show only the remainder data.

I just need a framework and I can make edits accordingly. Many thanks!

Table 1:

| P | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 14 | 51 | 21 | 51 |
| ZYX | 00 | 23 | 78 | 89 |
| XYZ | 55 | 56 | 91 | 55 |

Table 2:

| P | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZYX | 11 | 21 | 31 |
| XYZ | 12 | 23 | 32 |
| ABC | 13 | 24 | 33 |

Comment: So split it and do 100000 at a time. Also there are other q with answers showing solutions on here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26673792/4961700

Answer (score 0):

I make a demo program and test with two table of each 900000 rows. I use a variant array approach. The program takes 18s to run.
Quicksort is a must to make the program fast. The Quicksort and FindinArray function both use some kind of log(n) algorithm to be fast.

```
Dim vArr1 As Variant, vArr2 As Variant
Dim vArr1a As Variant, vArr2a As Variant
Dim last1 As Long, last2 As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim t As Double

t = Timer
last1 = 900001 'Or some method to find the last row
last2 = 900001

vArr1 = Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(last1, 5))
vArr2 = Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last2, 5)) 'One more column to store index
vArr1a = Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 6), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(last1, 6))
vArr2a = Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 6), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last2, 5))

For i = 1 To last1 - 1
    vArr1a(i, 1) = "" 'clear
Next i
For i = 1 To last2 - 1
    vArr2(i, 5) = i 'index
    vArr2a(i, 1) = "" 'clear
Next i
Call Quicksort2(vArr2, 1, 1, last2 - 1)

For i = 1 To last1 - 1
    j = FindinArray2(vArr2, vArr1(i, 1), 1, 0)
        If Abs(vArr1(i, 2) - vArr1(i, 3)) = 0 Then  'Criterion to compare columns in table1
            vArr1a(i, 1) = "abc"
        End If
        
        If j > 0 Then
            If Abs(vArr1(i, 2) - vArr2(j, 2)) = 0 Then 'Criterion to compare columns in table1 with columns in table2
                vArr1a(i, 1) = "false"
                vArr2a(vArr2(j, 5), 1) = "false" 'write back based on index
            End If
        End If
Next i
Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 6), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(last2, 6)) = vArr1a
Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 5), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last2, 5)) = vArr2a
MsgBox Round(Timer - t, 2)
```

Comment: this is not working. "Call Quicksort2" is giving a Sub or Function not defined error.

Comment: You need to get the quicksort function somewhere. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function), and also the search function.